# ui-grid api undefined after return from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Please go through plunker

```
 vm.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'deviceName'},
            {field: 'ip'},
            {
                field: 'Action', enableSorting: false,
                cellTemplate: '/monitoring_page/modals/buttonTemplate.html'
            }
        ],
        data: vm.dataStack,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            vm.gridApiSource = gridApi;
        }
    };
 //api call after coming from ui-bootstrap modal
  vm.gridApiSource.core.refresh();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Oxo8XdQCysOUvfvhD82z?p=preview

In console gridApiSoucrce is undefined. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Figured it out of after a bit of work - Click for Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJuv6U2UfZG7UAFdBwLa?p=preview):

1. Add `appScopeProvider: vm` to your grid options
2. Redeclare your grid as `<div ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-save-state class="cover-block"></div>`
3. Change your `body` declaration to `<body ng-controller="monitoringCtrl as vm">` and update all your calls to use vm.

   ```
   Example:  ng-click="monitoringCtrl.addDevice()"
   ```

   should now be:

   ```
   ng-click="vm.addDevice()"
   ```
4. Remove `ng-controller="monitoringCtrl as monitoringCtrl` from button.html, it is creating 8 instances of your controller due to that line of code.
5. **Test It Out**

[image]

If this works for you, please accept it for future users to replicate.